# Alerting if share on VM has had no activity in a specified period

Tags: azure, alert, azure-monitoring

I have a folder on a windows VM in azure.
An external process copies files onto this folder on a very regular basis.

I want to monitor this folder and get a notification if the number of files does not change within a specified period, as this tells me there is an issue with the file writer process or the file reader process.

I thought i may be able to do this with azure monitor but am now unsure if it is possible.

My questions are:

- is this possible with azure monitor?
- if not, is there a relatively simple way of monitoring this without scheduling scripts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, azure monitor does not support this kind of operation, and there is no other simple way for this.

The only way I can think of is using code to check the folder(seems you don't like this) periodically, then send proper notification to you.